# User is not prompted for a password after signing out from local B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

We are using msal-react library to login to Azure ADB2C. We support both externally federated users and "local" users, which are stored in our Azure ADB2C tenant. However, when my "local" B2C user signs out, even though I see tokens gone from the browser session storage, I am not asked for a password during next login and I am automatically logged in. When I close the browser it works, but not in the same browser session. Is this a bug in msal-react logout?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

User is not prompted for a password after signing out from local B2C since the session cookie is still present. You can force re-authentication:

- Adding the `?prompt=login` to the [/authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code) request. Eg: `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?prompt=login&...`

Or

- Configuring [Azure AD B2C session behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior).

Comment: We want to keep SSO behavior, meaning if a user is signed in to B2C via one application, they don't need to reauthenticate in another application. If we force reauthentication it won't happen. This solution seems like a workaround and not a fix.

Comment: Ok I see. Session cookie should get removed once the `end_session_endpoint` is being hit. This after calling the proper [MSAL logging out method](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md). If that's not happening can you tell me what @azure/msal-react version are you using?

Comment: Thanks! We found that the issue is n our code. We are not doing proper MSAL logging out method due to the bug in our code.